# Random sequence of html div tags position

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, random

There is four Div tags in this GridView with `ID="NUMBER1"` `ID="NUMBER2"` `ID="NUMBER3"` `ID="NUMBER4"` values and i want to change the sequence of their position in page randomly in every row of the gridview. 
what is the best and most simple SERVER SIDE method to do this.
I'm new to asp.net using C# language.

```
<body>
    <asp:GridView OnRowCommand="SelectedPollGridView_RowCommand" ID="SelectedPollGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="QuesID" DataSourceID="SelectedPollSqlDataSource">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Questions">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div runat="server" id="MainDiv" class="text-right col-md-12">
                        <div class="row ">
                            <div dir="rtl" class="col-md-12 text-right">
                                <p runat="server" id="BodyPTag"><%#Eval("Body") %></p>
                                <asp:Label Visible="false" ID="QuesIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("QuesID") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="NUMBER1" runat="server" class="row ">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div dir="rtl" runat="server" id="Div2" class="text-right col-md-11">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("O1") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                                <div runat="server" id="Div3" class="text-right col-md-1">
                                    <asp:Button CommandArgument='<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>' CommandName="O1" CssClass='<%#Eval("O1Css") %>' ID="O1Button" runat="server" Text="Option 1" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="NUMBER2" runat="server" class="row ">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div dir="rtl" runat="server" id="Div4" class="text-right col-md-11">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("O2") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                                <div runat="server" id="Div5" class="text-right col-md-1">
                                    <asp:Button CommandArgument='<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>' CommandName="O2" CssClass='<%#Eval("O2Css") %>' ID="O2Button" runat="server" Text="Option 2" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="NUMBER3" runat="server" class="row ">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div dir="rtl" runat="server" id="Div6" class="text-right col-md-11">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("O3") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                                <div runat="server" id="Div7" class="text-right col-md-1">
                                    <asp:Button CommandArgument='<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>' CommandName="O3" CssClass='<%#Eval("O3Css") %>' ID="O3Button" runat="server" Text="Option 3" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div  id="NUMBER4" runat="server" class="row ">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div dir="rtl" runat="server" id="Div8" class="text-right col-md-11">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("O4") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                                <div runat="server" id="Div9" class="text-right col-md-1">
                                    <asp:Button CommandArgument='<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>' CommandName="O4" CssClass='<%#Eval("O4Css") %>' ID="O4Button" runat="server" Text="Option 4" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SelectedPollSqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GUOTSConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT QuesID, Body, O1, O2, O4, O3, O1Css, O2Css, O4Css, O3Css, Time, BookRange, UserID, CourseID, Code FROM Question WHERE (UserID = @userid) AND (Code = @code)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="code" QueryStringField="code" />
            <asp:SessionParameter Name="userid" SessionField="userid" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</body>
```

Comment: Random random? As in they switch around where they are on the page when you refresh?  Or do you mean 'arbitrary' as in they have a specific order that does not change but which is not like their order in the code?

Comment: in fact this is a online exam and i want to display the sequence of option randomly for every question for every user so they can't tell the number of correct option to each other :).

Answer (score 2):

the following will do what you want.

[Working FIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/b4k65/1/)

first, change your current divs to give each row a class name we can pick out in our script, like "randomDiv". We could have used "row" but i was afraid you were using that in more places than just these divs.

```
<div id="NUMBER1" runat="server" class="row randomDiv">
```

then on document ready run the following javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var divs= $(".randomDiv");
        for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
            var target = Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length -1) + 1;
            var target2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length -1) +1;
            divs.eq(target).before(divs.eq(target2));
        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is there a server side method? because if users turn java script off in their browser, it will not happen. and this is critical and have to happen any way. thank you very much.

Comment: do people still do that? turn javascript off in their browsers?  That seems so 1997.

Comment: in fact this is a online exam and i want to display the sequence of options randomly for every question for every user so they can't tell the number of correct option to each other.

Comment: Because you're using a gridview i think you lose some control.  Repeater may give you the opportunity to write some more code within each loop, but its been so long since i've messed with either I wouldnt quote me on that.  You'd have to write your own c# randomizing logic and put it inside your repeater as it spits out divs

Comment: this is almost impossible because i have to change and rewrite my whole code. thank you very much.

Comment: if you want a server side solution you're going to have to rewrite some code, or at the very least, inject a good bit of code around what you already have.

Comment: just one more thing. how should i run this code?
after page load? or what?

Comment: i have updated my answer to show you how to run it.  Basically the code would exist inside a document.ready inside <script> tags

Comment: is it possible to populate this four divs in server side and set their position randomly?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45134/discussion-between-erikrunia-and-mahdi-hesari)

Comment: script works fine in the fiddle, I have no idea what you've implemented locally.  http://jsfiddle.net/b4k65/1/

Comment: yes it works for your sample but maybe the problem is, Div tags placed in a gridview template.