# Missing elements when randomizing order of list items in page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, random

I am trying to develop a little test for an educational website and I want to randomize the order of the questions and exercises and later down the line the order of the answers under each question with a set of radio buttons. I have tried the code I found on two separate questions (namely [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095247/random-sequence-of-html-div-tags-position/21095775#21095775) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483241/random-div-order-on-page-load)), although both the answers were practically the same. The code that I am using does what I want to some extent, but parts of my test are missing sometimes (most of the time I get 5 questions and 2-3 exercises instead of 6 and 4). How do I correct this? Full code sample in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chalarangelo/xnz26ngb/) (some irrelevant things from back-end are there, ignore them - content is placeholder to make debugging easier), as well as the javascript/jQuery code on its own below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var questions = $('.question');
        for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
            var target = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length - 1) + 1;
            var target2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length - 1) + 1;
            questions.eq(target).before(questions.eq(target2));
        }

        var exercises = $(".exercise");
        for (var j = 0; j < exercises.length; j++) {
            var target = Math.floor(Math.random() * exercises.length - 1) + 1;
            var target2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * exercises.length - 1) + 1;
            exercises.eq(target).before(exercises.eq(target2));
        }
    });
```

**P.S. #1:** The website's back-end is built with Asp.Net and C#, if that has anything to do with the problem.

**P.S. #2:** Run the fiddle four or five times and count the number of questions and exercises to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your code so that `target` will not be same as `target2`:

JavaScript

```
var questions = $('.question');
for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  var target = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length - 1) + 1;
  var target2 = target;
  while(target2 === target) {
    target2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length - 1) + 1;
  }
  questions.eq(target).before(questions.eq(target2));
}

var exercises = $(".exercise");
for (var j = 0; j < exercises.length; j++) {
  var target = Math.floor(Math.random() * exercises.length - 1) + 1;
  var target2 = target;
  while(target2 === target) {
    target2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * exercises.length - 1) + 1;
  }
  exercises.eq(target).before(exercises.eq(target2));
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/xnz26ngb/1/)

Comment: Yea, that seems to have solved the issue. So the problem was that sometimes the two random targets were the same, entirely forgot to check that. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to prepend an item before itself :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume all the `.question` / `.exercise` elements are in the same parent.

They way I'd approach it would be:

1. Grab the questions/exercises as an array and detach them
2. Randomize the array, in [any of serveral ways addressed in this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)
3. Append them

For instance:

```js
function randomize(selector) {
  // Get the elements and their parent
  var elements = $(selector);
  var parent = elements.eq(1).parent();
  
  // Detach, get array
  elements = elements.detach().get();
  
  // Shuffle it
  shuffle(elements);
  
  // Attach
  parent.append(elements);
}

// From https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/157247
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}

randomize(".question");
randomize(".exercise");
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="question">Question 1</li>
  <li class="question">Question 2</li>
  <li class="question">Question 3</li>
  <li class="question">Question 4</li>
  <li class="question">Question 5</li>
</ul>
Exercises:
<ul>
  <li class="exercise">Exercise 1</li>
  <li class="exercise">Exercise 2</li>
  <li class="exercise">Exercise 3</li>
  <li class="exercise">Exercise 4</li>
  <li class="exercise">Exercise 5</li>
  <li class="exercise">Exercise 6</li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works like a charm, I suppose I can then run it again on the different questions' radio buttons set using a selector based on the `name` attribute.

Comment: **Why this is not the accepted answer:** I believe this method to be superior to my original code as it is more generalised and allows for a more versatile solution that can work without rewriting any code, however the issue at hand was that my code had some problem I could not figure out and I needed to know what that was and how to fix it. Therefore I am accepting @Arg0n's answer as it was more enlightening in my case and taught me something more valuable.

Comment: @AngelosChalaris: And fair enough! :-)